# How to create a new dataframe using existing dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe df. Now, I took a backup of this df using:

```
df_backup = df
```

Later on in my code, I deleted few records from the original df using:

```
df.drop(df.index[indexes], inplace = True)
```

these rows gets deleted from the backup as well.
It looks like `df_backup` is just a copy of `df`. How do I decouple both?

If I change anything to `df`, it shouldn't affect `df_backup`.

Answer (score 1):

you can decouple them by making an actual copy (a copy is a separate object)

```
df_backup = df.copy()
```

as Anthony Sottile pointed out, you were creating another reference to your original dataframe rather than creating a new object. Which means you could change either your `df` or `df_backup` and both would show that change. He also suggested a [good link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference) to help understand this

Comment: might be worth adding that `df_backup = df` does not create a copy (since python is a referential language) and just makes two references pointing to the same object.  OP seems confused about this :)  perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference might clear some stuff up too